# Asynchronous callback passing REST/JSON web service framework?

Tags: json, rest, asynchronous, callback, frameworks

I'm looking for a REST/JSON web service framework that has generic built-ins for receiving a callback URL, storing the parameters for the request, queuing the job, and calling the caller's callback URL with the response, once the job has completed. Does such a thing exist in any language?